# Q: NetSuite E-Commerce - Source Custom Entity Fields to Reference Checkout

Tags: reference, e-commerce, netsuite, checkout, suitecommerce

I have a custom entity field placed inside NetSuite, now I have to source the value of this field to my Reference Checkout as I'll use the value as a condition for which payment method to show on the shop.

Any ideas how to do this? I've searched the SuiteAnswers and got no significant help there.

Thank you!

I've looked into using view.model.get('customfield ID here') but it has not worked. I've also already defined the field on models.js. Just not sure if I placed it properly.

Render function of Order Wizard Payment Method Selector

```
,   render: function()
            {
                if (this.wizard.hidePayment())
                {
                    this.$el.empty();
                    this.trigger('change_label_continue');
                    return;
                }

                if (!this.selectedModule)
                {
                    var selected_payment = this.model.get('paymentmethods').findWhere({primary: true})
                    ,   selected_type;

                    var creditlevelhold = this.wizard.model.get('creditlevelhold'); < -- this is the custom field
                    console.log(creditlevelhold);

                    if(selected_payment){
                        selected_type = selected_payment.get('type');
                    }
                    else if(this.wizard.options.profile.get('paymentterms') && creditlevelhold === ''){
                        selected_type = 'invoice';
                    }
                    this.setModuleByType(selected_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be available like:

```
this.wizard.model.get('options')['custbodyxxx']
```